# Can I obtain the parameters of the website using Brython?

Tags: html, brython

I am currently trying to use Brython for the website I am making, but I cannot get the data from the user for my program.

I set up a box for the user to type in an ID...

```html
<form name="levelid" action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="id" id="idresposne">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

...then the current method I use is to make it append the URL using the GET method. This makes the URL looks like this.

```
https://mywebsiteurl.com/website.html?id=12345678
```

I know I can extract the `id` parameter using `window.location.search` and then `URLSearchParams` in JavaScript, with a code like this. This allows me to use the variable `id_i_needed` which now holds the argument, `12345678` for the above example URL.

```js
var levelqm = window.location.search;
levelqm = new URLSearchParams(levelqm);
var levelid = levelqm.get("id");
```

However, I cannot seem to find anything given by the Brython documentation that it can obtain URL information, nor find a way to make Brython communicate with JavaScript.

Is there something that allows me to do a similar thing as the JS code? If this is not possible with Brython, is there a library that I can look for to achieve the same thing?

I wrote the code that processes that ID in Python, which is why I am fiddling with Brython in the first place.

Comment: It looks like it is described in [the documentation](https://brython.info/static_doc/en/query.html).

Comment: It works, thanks! Quick question: do I need to follow up on this question or keep it as is?

Comment: You can [delete it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) or [answer it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Thanks to Hernán Alarcón for directing me to this.)

Because I used the GET request, which will append the parameters to the URL, Brython has an attribute `query` that searches for URL parameters.

Using the expression `document.query['id']` will give `12345678` for the example URL. This yields the same results as the JavaScript code posted in the question.

Apparently I missed [this page of documentation](https://brython.info/static_doc/en/query.html) at Brython.